# How to create Editable PDF by ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, pdf

How to create editable PDF using ASP.NET. I want to create a Pdf from a master template, edit it (fill some value(input not from database)) and save. Is it possible without using a 3rd party?

If some sample code available it will be great

Answer (score 1):

I use [PDF4NET](http://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/products.htm) in a couple of projects, can definitely recommend it. There are [code samples](http://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/samples.htm) on their website.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the open-source [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/), which is a port from [iText](http://www.lowagie.com/iText/) (java).
[Here](http://itext.ugent.be/library/com/lowagie/examples/forms/FormTextField.java) is a code sample that creates a form with a text field (it's java but the iTextSharp interface is nearly identical)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the [ReportViewer control](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/).

You can create a "report template", assign data to it in runtime (fill in values), render it, and save the result.

Answer (score 0):

I like http://dynamicpdf.com they have a free community edition which allows you to programmatically create PDF's from scratch. The paid products offer much more functionality and they have a designer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Aspose.Pdf.Kit](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/default.aspx) for this purpose. In fact, it can be used either in a ASP.NET or Windows application. You can download the trial version. Have a look at the related documentation; that might be of some help.